# what date format is 2022-07-24T19:00:00.000Z?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have this code running in my Kernel.php to blast an email at a set date:

```
$schedule->call(function () {BlastEmail::blastAll();})->hourly()->when(function() {
            $targetDate = strtotime(ENV('LAUNCH_COUNTDOWN'));
            $currentDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
            if($currentDate >= $targetDate) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

I realized that the format of $currentDate is Y-m-d, while the LAUNCH_COUNTDOWN I set is 2022-07-24T19:00:00.000Z. is this going to run successfully, or do I have to change the currentDate format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` to parse it properly:

```php
$schedule->call(function() {

})->hourly()->when(function() {
    $launchDate = Carbon::parse(env('LAUNCH_COUNTDOWN'));
    return Carbon::now()->greaterThan($launchDate);
});
```

This way the heavy lifting is done by Carbon. Note that this function will be called hourly till eternity after the given date.

Also, you shouldn't be calling `env()` in your code manually, as that function is designed to be called only in config files in `[project]/config/someconfig.php` so that it can be cached using `php artisan config:cache`. I know it is an easy thing to do but it's nicer to use something like:

file: `config/project.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'launch_countdown' => env('LAUNCH_COUNTDOWN', false),
];
```

You then call `app('project.launch_countdown')` which defaults to `false` when the env variable is not set.